# Usage of the phrase " just because" at the end of sentences

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-ends

Usually, *because* links the premise and the conclusion. But there is one usage of the word I come across often, not in contemporary writings but older works.

These are of the form: "[subject did something] just because", where the the phrase "just because" is used to imply that the doer's actions were not guided by any purpose and the act was performed only for the sake of it, or on an impulse.

How can this usage of the word *because* be explained?

Comment: You're asking about the phrase "just because", not simply using "because" at the end of a sentence.  You should edit (the title, especially) to reflect this.   (Unless you can find an example of 'because at the end' that is not a 'just because'.

Comment: I cannot see any valid reason to end a sentence with the word "because".

Answer (score 4):

How? Just because...

Sorry, I couldn't resist. I don't have an ANSWER, but I have a theory. I think the phrase is verbal shorthand, that has no proper literary form. What I mean: I believe the phrase may have come from people saying "because... because..." not having a reason, then "just because!"

Answer (score 3):

The [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Just%20because.) defines "just because" as meaning "because you could".

It's really just a 'circular' response:

> I did it because I could do it (no other reason)
>   He did it because he could do it (no other reason)

Comment: That's an interesting definition - I always interpreted it as "because you wanted to".

Comment: @AzulaR.  Yes, as you can see, I was just quoting what I found, but I agree with you that it can equally well mean "because I wanted to". In fact, *Just because **could** mean whatever you **want** it to mean, just because!*

Comment: that is delightful

Comment: "Why did you do that?" "Just because (I could do)."