# What is the Implied Meaning Behind when someone answers a Question with "Because."

Tags: american-english, word-usage, parts-of-speech, dialogue

I was watching Season 3 of "The West Wing"(# the Greatest show on TV). Episode 9: Bartlet for America.

The premise is that Leo McGarry, the White House Chief-Of-Staff is

> under an Congressional Hearing in relation to the President Hiding his MS

And he discusses his alcoholic Past with the Lawyer; below is the excerpt

Leo: My father was an alcoholic, his father was an alcoholic. So in my case...

Lawyer: ...Ain't nothing but a family thing.

Leo: That's right.

Lawyer: Who knows?

Leo: Josh Lyman and the President.

Lawyer: Why nobody else?

Leo: **Because**.

Lawyer: That's a little boy's answer.

Leo: I went to rehab, my friends embraced me when I got out.
You relapse, it's not like that.
"Get away from me," that's what it's like.

Can anyone explain to me what is Implied by that answer. Because. at first glance doesn't answer anything. Or is it something to be gleaned by yourself.

Comment: But you didn't actually use a spoiler tag. If there's a line of text you want to hide until somebody moves their mouse over it, put `<!` at its start. I just made that change to the one line I *think* you were referring to. Feel free to change it to something else if I got it wrong. (I'm also not sure what the asterisks are doing at the start and end of the conversation.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of the phrase " just because" at the end of sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118784/usage-of-the-phrase-just-because-at-the-end-of-sentences)

Comment: I don't think that the question here is substantially the same as the one about "just because" from six years ago. I also note that the answers to the "just because" question are pretty marginal. even as applied to that particular question. With regard to the context of this question, they are scarcely helpful at all.

Comment: The lawyer says "That's a little boy's answer", but to me it's more like the answer an adult might give _to_ a child, meaning "because that is the way things are, and you have to accept it".

Comment: https://youtu.be/XFTnFhGuaBQ

Answer (score 2):

Just saying "Because" is a way of avoiding answering the question. It's a cheap way to skip a question and kids use it a lot so adults get tired of it quickly.